# Bootstrap 3 styles not loading with Spring boot and WebJars

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, webjars

I added the following dependencies to my Spring boot (using version 2.1.15) project:

```xml
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.7-1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

On my Thymeleaf page I included the following CSS files and scripts:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/css/bootstrap.min.css}">

<script th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/js/bootstrap.min.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

To load the template, I defined the following controller mapping:

```java
@RequestMapping(name = "/")
public String loadMainWeb() {
    return "index";
}
```

However, when I run the application, the Bootstrap styles are not loading. I tested this by adding the `btn` and `btn-primary` classes to a button. Why are these styles not loading?

The full project can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/PawelSzymanski89/B2B-Panel).

Comment: where are your bootstrap files?

Comment: Im using webjars im not downloading bootstrap directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your controller mapping. You're currently using the following mapping:

```java
@RequestMapping(name = "/")
public String loadMainWeb() {
    return "index";
}
```

However, you used the `name` property in stead of the `path` property on the `@RequestMapping` annotation. By leaving away the `path` property, you actually tell Spring that you want to apply this controller mapping for all endpoints.

That means that when you run the application, you're actually loading the `index.html` page when you're trying to load the WebJars files.

To solve this, you should use `path` in stead of `name`:

```java
@RequestMapping(path = "/") // Use 'path'
public String loadMainWeb() {
    return "index";
}
```